# pandas multi-level index series: index value convert to dataframe columns name

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas question: I have a multi-level index series as following

```
index1    index2
A         2022-01-01    1.0
          2022-01-02    2.0
          2022-01-03    3.0
          2022-01-04    4.0
B         2022-01-01    5.0
          2022-01-02    6.0
          2022-01-03    7.0
          2022-01-04    8.0
```

change it into a single level dataframe as following

```
              A       B
index2
2022-01-01    1.0     5.0
2022-01-02    2.0     6.0
2022-01-03    3.0     7.0
2022-01-04    4.0     8.0
```

I know that a set of for loop will do the trick,
but is there any simple and elegant way to implement this?
please help here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Series.unstack` with `level=0`:

```
new_df = s.unstack(level=0)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
index1        A    B
index2              
2022-01-01  1.0  5.0
2022-01-02  2.0  6.0
2022-01-03  3.0  7.0
2022-01-04  4.0  8.0
```